# IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@xxxxxxxx has been closed already

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

After restarting a Spring Boot application using actuator, we are not able to start the application.

We have Spring Boot application, where we want to implement a functionality where we can restart the application using actuator. Application is able to run but when we call `restart()` then it wont up and throw the exception:

> "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1b84f475
>   has been closed already"

```java
    //Controller Class
    @PostMapping("/restartApp")
        public void restartUsingActuator() {
            restartService.restartApp();
        }


    //Service Class
    @Autowired private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;

        public void restartApp() {
            System.out.println("in restartApp");

            ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = restartEndpoint.restart();
            ctx.refresh();

        }
```

Expecting to run the application.

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app):

> it’s important to recreate the context in a separate non-daemon thread — this way we prevent the JVM shutdown, triggered by the close method, from closing our application. Otherwise, our application would stop

The error you're seeing means the spring application has been stopped, so there is no injected `RestartEndpoint` service to use to restart the application.

That article should help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue because another process was running on the same port. Stopping that process solved the issue for me. I tried to use `fuser -k 8080/tcp` but was unsuccesful, so I killed all running java processes using killall -9 java. That fixed it, but it would be better to kill only the processes using that port.